# How to give hover effect to just an image within a div with text under it?

Tags: html, css

Here is my example I want the image to be scaled on hover and the read more text be shown with icons in the middle of the image on hover :

```
<div id="grid-background">><div class="container">
            <h1>some text</h1>

    <div class="grid-container">
            <ul class="rig columns-3">
                <li class="asd">
                    <div class="rig-cell">

                    <img src="img/pri_001.jpg" />
                    <span class="rig-text"><div>read more<i class="fa fa-search"></i></div></span>
                    <span class="rig-share"><div><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i><i class="fa fa-eye"></i><i class="fa fa-share"></i></div></span>

                    <h3>some text</h3>
                    <p>some text</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
</div></div>
```

When I scale the image on hover it goes out of its limits go beyond the text,I just want to put transparent filter on hover and show the icons with read more text.

Css

```
.container h1 {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    color:#35536f;
    font-weight: 800;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.container hr {
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-color: rgba(202, 190, 158, .5); 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    margin: 25px 0;
    clear: both;
}

.centered {
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    direction:rtl;
    padding-top:2%;
}
#grid-background {width:100%;background:#f4f2ed;}

.grid-container {
    display:inline-block;
}

ul.rig {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0px;
    margin-left: -2.5%; /* should match li left margin */
}
ul.rig li {
    display: inline-block;
    *display:inline;/*for IE6 - IE7*/
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 0 2.5% 2.5%;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ddd;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    position:relative;


}

.rig-cell {
    /*margin:12px;
    box-shadow:0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);*/
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}


ul.rig li img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    transform:scale(1);
    transition:all 1s;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;position:relative;
}
.img-cell {position:relative;}
ul.rig li .img-cell:after {
    content: '\A';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;cursor:pointer;
}
ul.rig li .img-cell:hover img{}


ul.rig li .img-cell:hover:after{opacity:1;}




ul.rig li h3 {
    margin: 0 0 5px;


}
ul.rig li p {
    font-size: .9em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #999;
}


ul.rig.columns-3 li {
    width: 30.83%; /* this value + 2.5 should = 33% */
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .container {
        width: auto;
        padding: 0 10px;
        padding-top:5%;
    }
    .container h1 {line-height:25px;}
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
    ul.rig {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    ul.rig li {
        width: 100% !important; /* over-ride all li styles */
        margin: 0 0 20px;
    }
        .container h1 {font-size:1rem}

}


.rig-text {
    display:table;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    top:50%;
    padding:1%;
    color:#fff;z-index:999;text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);/*For older IE*/
    transform:translateY(-20px);
    transition:all .3s;cursor:pointer;
}
.rig-share {
    display:table;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    font-size:20px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    top:65%;
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);/*For older IE*/
    padding:1%;
    color:#fff;z-index:999;text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
    transition:all .3s;cursor:pointer;  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
.rig-share i:hover{opacity:.6;}
ul.rig li .img-cell:hover .rig-share{
    opacity: .8;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
.rig-share i {margin:0 5px;}

ul.rig li .img-cell:hover .rig-text {
    transform:translateY(0px);
    opacity:0.9;transition-delay:.1s;
}
ul.rig li .img-cell:hover .rig-text2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -30px) rotateX(30deg);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -30px) rotateX(30deg);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -30px) rotateX(30deg);
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -30px) rotateX(30deg);}
```

I was adding a div contain the image, icons and read more but on php the effect doesn't work I want to remove the div and keep everything working.

Comment: Where is your css?

Comment: Just edited my post, look back on it

Comment: is there any solution?

Comment: Iam stuck......

Comment: One thing to change is line 16. Do the code like this <div><span class="rig-text">read more<i class="fa fa-search"></i></span></div> you also have an extra </div> in line 26, just before </body>  give me a few more minutes

Comment: take your time I will give it a try